# Spring boot application thread safe

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cassandra, apache-kafka

I have a **Spring-boot Java** application which streams data continuously from **Kafka** and saves it to the database **Cassandra** after applying business logic.

Below are the pseudo classes and functions which resemble my application fully.

**KafkaStreamer**

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableKafka
 public class KafkaStreamer {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyDomain.class);

    @Autowired
    private MyController myController;

    @KafkaListener(topics = "${my-topic}", group = "${my-group}")
    public void streamFromKafka(String payload) {
        myController.processPayload(payload);
        LOGGER.info("I am continously streaming data from Kafka "
                + "and forwarding it to controller for further processing...!");
    }
}
```

**MyController**

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyDomain.class);

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    public void processPayload(String payload) {
        myService.applyBusinessLogic(payload);
        LOGGER.info("Send to service for business-logic processing");
    }
}
```

**MyService**

```
@Service
public class MyService {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyDomain.class);

    @Autowired
    private MyDomain myDomain;

    public void applyBusinessLogic(String payload) {
        myDomain.saveToDatabase(payload);
        LOGGER.info("Applied business-logic");
    }
}
```

**MyDomain**

```
    @Repository
    public class MyDomain {

        private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyDomain.class);

   @Autowired
    private CassandraOperations cassandraTemplate;

    /** The session. */
    private Session session = null;

        public void saveToDatabase(String payload) {
            saveToTableA(payload);
            saveToTableB(payload);
            // Hello, I have saved data to database
            LOGGER.info("Saved data to database");
        }

        private void saveToTableB(String payload) {
             if (session == null)
                   session = cassandraTemplate.getSession();
             session.execute(payload);
        }

        private void saveToTableA(String payload) {
            if (session == null)
                   session = cassandraTemplate.getSession()
          session.execute(payload);

        }

    }
```

The above pseudo code resembles my original application fully.

As you can see I do **not have any class level variables** **other than logger, some auto-wired variable and cassandra session in MyDomain class**

According to my knowledge, **auto-wire** by default in spring-boot is **singleton**.

I am passing payload (which is my message from Kafka) from one class to another class in function argument rather setting as the class level property of other class.

My question is,

**Is my above application architecture or code thread safe ?**.

Can Autowire create problem as by default it gives singleton reference of a class ( a point to note here is I do not have any class level variables other than logger and auto-wire variable)

If you feel if there exists a better way or anything, please feel free to write.

Many thanks from me.

Comment: Spring boot has nothing to do with singleton. The spring default behavior is however singleton, but you define yourself with your annotations how your classes behave.

Comment: What you will suggest, according to my above case I should use `singleton or prototype `

Comment: Singletons without the use of class variables are generally thread safe (some object dependencies: All your objects in the called methods need to be thread safe). With that, I would first try to use the code with singletons, review that specific part and avoid prototype use.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution stops to be thread-safe if you start to mutate the state of the shared object.

For example if you'd have a `payload` property in the `MyDomain` singleton Spring bean and set its value in the `saveToDatabase` and a bit later (even in the same method) consult it, that would be mutation and your code won't be thread-safe.

For example:

```
@Repository
public class MyDomain {

   private String payload;

   public void saveToDatabase(String payload) {
        this.payload = payload;
        saveToTableA();
        saveToTableB();
   }


   private void saveToTableA() {
      tableA.save(this.payload);
   }
```

In this case when several threads call your `saveToDatabase` concurrently with different values, there is no guarantee what value you really will save to the DB in the `saveToTableA()`.